# Make sure app developed in XCode6.1 will run on iOS5.1 and wont be rejected by iTunes

Tags: ipad, xcode6.1, ios5.1

I have customers with iPad1 so iOS5.1 is the limit. I had to upgrade to XCode 6.1 cause XCode5 wont submit to iTunes any more, you need at least 5.1 or higher or so.

So since then deployment target starts from iOS6.0.

I managed to make XCode6.1 to go lower, down to iOS5.0 by changing Architectures to $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) and by setting Valid Architectures to armv7 only (cause it wont build onto device if I have default set).

Here is my questions - Did anybody publish the app lately that would work with iOS 5.0 and above, if yes how did you set it up in XCode to have lower deployment iOS?

And, would iTunes reject the app for having only one valid architecture, i.e armv7?

Thanks